The return type 'IsolatedAudioHandler' isn't a 'AudioPlayerHandler',
I'm trying to use the audio_service package to make my AudioHandler accessible in background isolate too. The problem here is that the documentation here shows something like this at the end of this:
// Wrap audio handler in IsolatedAudioHandler:
_audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
  builder: () => IsolatedAudioHandler(
    MyAudioHandler(),
    portName: 'my_audio_handler',
  ),
);
// From another isolate, obtain a proxy reference:
_proxyAudioHandler = await IsolatedAudioHandler.lookup(
  portName: 'my_audio_handler',
);

Now, when I try to do that, I get
The return type 'IsolatedAudioHandler' isn't a 'AudioPlayerHandler',

This is my code:
audioController.audioHandler = await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => IsolatedAudioHandler(
      AudioPlayerHandlerImpl(),
      portName: 'my_audio_handler',
    ),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.abc.abcd',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      // androidStopForegroundOnPause: false,
    ),
  );

P.S
Just found out what the cause is, but still don't know what the solution is:
So I am using an AudioPlayerHandler instead of the AudioHandler, provided by the just_audio package and that is just an interface to add a few functions like queuesState and moveQueueItem.
I do not know though how to avoid using it.
So, if anyone has ever used this before, please help me out here. Thanks
